# How to change the order of achievements on Steamworks?

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

When creating a new achievement on steamworks it automatically gets added to the end of the achievements list and I can't figure out a way to change the order of the achievements. Do I really need to delete them all and create them again in order or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the order or id of achievements on steamworks, sorry to be the bearer of bad news.